# IE<9 bind event to invisible radio

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, radio-button

I am having issues with `onChange()` and radio buttons styled `display:none;` which should be triggered by the label they are wrapped in is clicked.

The onChange() handler does not activate in IE8, IE7 when the following CSS is applied to the radio buttons.

```
#questionFrm input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Another method that I tried involved moving the form element off the screen in a similarly to how many drop-down menus work. Firefox, however, refuses to move the radio button off the screen.

```
#questionFrm input[type="radio"] {
    position:absolute;
    top:-99;left:-99;
}
```

Radios hidden, pretty but does not work - http://jsfiddle.net/fHTwr/

Radios shown, ugly but works - http://jsfiddle.net/fHTwr/1/

Comment: What does this have to do with the Revealing Module Pattern?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would help, but how about something like the [EcmaScript 5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) or some other [fallback mechanism](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)?

Comment: well, nothing. That i should have probably left that out since it is irrelevant to the question. I just want to hide the form element and control it from the label and the two approaches I could think of have issues in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using onClick() first, if it doesn't work you could do something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
var currVal = 0;
function changeIt() {
    document.getElementById('changeMe').value = currVal++;
    document.getElementById('changeMe').onchange();
}
function handle_change(elem) {
    alert(elem.value);
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

<input type="button" onclick="changeIt()" value="Change It"/>
<input id="changeMe" type="text" value="" style="display: none;" onchange="handle_change(this)"/>

  </body>
</html>
```